# Rails: Where query syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I seriously cannot solve this syntax error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "07"
LINE 1: ...WHERE (post_id = 13 AND created_at > 2012-08-27 07:13:26) ...
```

This is what my query looks like:

```
Post.where(post_filter_params_where)

    def post_filter_params_where
      case params[:post_filter].to_i
      when 1
        "post_id = #{params[:id]}"
      when 2
        "post_id = #{params[:id]}"
      when 3
        time = 24.hours.ago.utc.to_s(:db)
        "post_id = #{params[:id]} AND created_at > #{time}"
      else
        "post_id = #{params[:id]}"
      end
    end
```

Comment: just posted, sorry about that

Comment: Would have been good if you posted your ruby code because this is a SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to prepend the querys from the function with `puts`

```
    def post_filter_params_where
      case params[:post_filter].to_i
      when 1
        puts 'post_id = ?', params[:id]
      when 2
        puts 'post_id = ?', params[:id]
      when 3
        puts 'post_id = ?', params[:id], 24.hours.ago.utc.to_s(:db)
      else
        puts 'post_id = ?', params[:id]
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Post.where('post_id = ? AND created_at > ?', params[:id], 24.hours.ago.utc.to_s(:db))
```

The error is because you concat the where condition and missed the quote for the date.

Comment: The problem with this is that I am actually returning the 'where' input from a function `Post.where(some_function)`. I posted an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you need to use `Post.where(some_function)`, because it would make more sense to provide a method like `Post.filter(params[:post_filter], params[:id])` - if you need to reuse your filter method, just write a module and include it in all related models.

Also your current code is open to SQL injection attacks. Never use ruby string interpolation to create sql strings, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Anyway, here's some code :)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.filter(filter, post_id)
    if filter.to_i == 3
      where('post_id = ? AND created_at > ?', post_id, 24.hours.ago.utc)
    else
      where('post_id = ?', post_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Then instead of using `Post.where(some_function)` in your controller, simply use `Post.filter(params[:post_filter], params[:id])`. Bonus point, better use some constant to describe what `3` means.